# Getting children pages or links of a page or link

Tags: python, php, web-scraping, web-crawler, parent-child

I'm trying to get the latest news via (https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement). To do this, I used the following code in python:

```
flag=0
while True:
    binance_code=requests.get("https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement")
    binance_soup=BeautifulSoup(binance_code.text,"html.parser")
    binance_news=binance_soup.find_all(class_="css-qinc3w")
    t1=binance_news[0].text
    if flag==0:
        sub_t1=t1
        flag+=1
    if sub_t1!=t1:
        flag=0
        print(t1)
        print(datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()))
```

But I realized that there is a delay of more than 5 minutes between creating the news and placing the link on the top page.
Is there a way to receive this news immediately after production, for example to be able to be notified of the creation of a new link or news by receiving the ("https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement") child links directly.

Please reply in any language this feature was provided!

Comment: You'll need to periodically check for presence by means of some hook (e.g. date and time of publication is later than the last one checked). If you talking about getting them out of some internal to the system place, if there's no API for it, it is probably not possible.

Comment: @rawrex Thanks for the reply. News links are a meaningless and unpredictable string and also unfortunately there's no API.